# How to remove delay on Python try: except:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I make an automation program by python.
It’s for a website.
And there is a random PopUp when I click it
So I added a Pop-up removal code that activates whenever the pop-up pops up.

It works well but the problem is that it takes a long time (about 5 secs each loop).
If I use that code again (under IF case script) it delays again.

What is the problem with my code?

this is my code below:

```
def is_element_exist():
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/button")
        return True
    except:
        return False


if is_element_exist():
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/button").click()

# auto click when pops up
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), '%s')]" % catLevel2).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), '%s')]" % catLevel3).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
if is_element_exist():
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/button").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), '%s')]" % catLevel4).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
if is_element_exist():
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/button").click()
```

Comment: this might sound ironic but you might want to try **time.sleep(2)** inside the **click()** statements.

Comment: Try to implement [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to handle popup

Comment: Also you'd better not to use absolute XPath. And instead of `find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), '%s')]" % catLevel3)` try `find_element_by_partial_link_text(catLevel3)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is going to make your code fast enough but I think you can change your comparison logic. Right now, you are checking if is_element_exist() while using driver.find() then if it's exist you are calling same code again. I'm sending my suggestion below.

```
def get_element_if_possible():
    try:
        return driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/button")
    except:
        return False
```

and now you can remove your if blocks below. just call get_element_if_possible() it will returns the element if it's there otherwise it returns false.